# JSTL table creation on JSP Page Load- no data in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, foreach, jstl

I am trying to creating a JSP home page that contains a table of varying sizes. I am wanting to use the forEach JSTL tag. The servlet is working correctly and is producing a list of two products. However this information does not appear on the final HTML.

If I call:

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaIntoJSP/products
```

the output is good.

If I call:

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaIntoJSP/default.jsp
```

the output is missing

Code as follows (default.jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix= "c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>default</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form action="products" method="get">
        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product" >
                <tr> 
                    <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td> 
                    <td><c:out value="${product.price}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${product.category}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${product.units}" /></td> 
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        </form>
        <h1>try again</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

The Servlet has the following

```
@WebServlet("/products")
public class ProductServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ProductServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        Product prod1   = new Product();
        prod1 = prod1.returnProduct();
        products.add(prod1);
        Product prod2   = new Product();
        prod2 = prod2.returnProduct();
        prod2 = prod2.returnProduct();
        products.add(prod2);


        request.setAttribute("products", products);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("default.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }    
}
```

Can anyone plese let me know why the products are not being found on the JSP?

Comment: What's the URL displayed in your browser's address bar when trying to display the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaIntoJSP/products
```

It calls the `ProductServlet` where `products` list is filled and forwarded to `default.jsp`

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaIntoJSP/default.jsp
```

If you call `default.jsp` directly  then `products` list will be `null` & because of that you can not see any out put on the screen.

### Update

Answer to your question from comment

**Do not write scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP**, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code. [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Use [`empty` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el006.htm#BNAIK) to check `products` list is `null` and empty. 
There is not `if-else` in EL, so you have to use `<c:choose><c:when>...`

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${!empty products}">
     //print the list 
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     //call the servlet
    <jsp:forward page="products"></jsp:forward> 
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

### Related

- [Tag choose](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html)

Comment: Thanks to Aniket and AdolAurion. The problem was that I was not making a call to the Servlet from the default.jsp I have since modified my code to include a conditional call to the servlet.

If anyone knows a cleaner way to do this I would be glad to hear.

<table>
<%   if (request.getAttribute("products") == null){ %>
 <jsp:forward page="products"></jsp:forward>
<%    } %>

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:8080/JavaIntoJSP/default.jsp` doesnt call the servlet. Therefore you wont get "products" into your request's attributes.

You should check on "default.jsp" whether "products" is available.